# JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType definition syntax issue

Tags: c#, arrays, definition, jsonconvert

I have the following code:

```
var definition = new { result = "", accountinformation = new[] { "" ,  "" , "" } };

var accountInformationResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(responseBody, definition);
```

The account information structure comes back from an endpoint as an array with each element being another array containing 3 strings. So the embedded array is not in a key value pair format. With the above definition accountinformation returns null. What should the syntax be for this structure?

For reference this is what is going on in the php endpoint.

```
$account_information[] = array( $billing_company, $customer_account_number, $customer_account_manager );
```

This first line is in a loop. Hence the multi-dimensional array.

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result, 'account_information'=>$account_information));
```

I know I could use dynamic but why the extra effort?

Comment: Can you see what happens if you change the name from `accountinformation` to `accountInformation` (capital 'I')?

Comment: I still get a null result with the capitalised I. I did try new[][] { "", "", "" } but that wouldn't even compile!

Comment: And account_information?

Comment: It doesn't like the underscore. I am changing the code in the other system to remove the underscore. After changing the code so both systems use accountinformation I now get another arror. JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'accountinformation', line 1, position 38. I assume this is the square bracket after new.

Comment: Check out my answer, got it working in a console application here.

Comment: For any other unfortunate soul who comes across this, the required syntax is var definition = new { result = "", accountinformation = new[,] { { "", "", "" } } };

Comment: @Jesse de Wit I think you left out your hyperlink.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240925/3883866)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your json will look something like this:

```
{
  "result": "the result",
  "account_information": [
    ["company1", "account_number1", "account_manager1"],
    ["company2", "account_number2", "account_manager2"]
  ]
}
```

In that case you should be able to deserialize with the following definition (note the underscore in account_information:

```
var definition = new { result = "", account_information = new List<string[]>() };
```

In json you are allowed to add extra properties as you please while your data model changes. So if you define a data model that does not include one of these properties, the property will simple be ignored. In your case the definition does not have a property called `account_information` (exactly), so this part of the json is ignored while deserializing.

EDIT:
If it's going to be an anonymous abject anyway, you may also consider parsing into a `JObject`:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
string firstCompany = obj["account_information"][0][0];
string secondCompany = obj["account_information"][1][0];
```

Comment: Your answer that included the list syntax returned null. In the comments above I detailed what worked for me. Which is: var definition = new { result = "", accountinformation = new[,] { { "", "", "" } } }

Comment: OK, then the json doesn't look the way I showed on top of my answer.

Comment: Not exactly, account_information would contain [["string", "string","string"],["string", "string", "string"] … ] etc for as many rows as there are data.

Comment: Well, updated my answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Yes your answer does in fact work. I am using your version. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can thank me by upvoting and marking this as the answer.